# Postgresql, string concatenation and sorting of records at the same time

Tags: postgresql

I have a set of records with a "data" field which is actually a JSON object. I would like to concatenate these JSON objects of a certain set of this records after I have sorted it.

This is my query:

```
select string_agg(data, ', ') 
       from timeseriesdata TS, atomicseries AT 
       where AT.timeseriesdata_ptr_id = TS.id 
       AND AT.atomic_id = 11 AND date between '2016-03-01' and '2016-03-30'
```

The above (almost) does what I want, however I would like to know if it is possible to sort data by the field `timestamp` of the TS table.

Comment: have you tried by adding an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Yes, I get this error: ERROR:  column "ts.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify the order in the `ORDER BY` clause, because at that point all you have left is a single row containing all the `data` aggregated in a single string (and so you don't have a `ts` column to order by anymore).

You need to specify the `ORDER BY` in the `STRING_AGG` function:

```
-- unspecified order
WITH d(ts, data) AS (
  VALUES
    (1 , 'json1'),
    (2 , 'json2'),
    (10, 'json10'),
    (3 , 'json3')
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(data, ',')
FROM d
;
┌──────────────────────────┐
│        string_agg        │
├──────────────────────────┤
│ json1,json2,json10,json3 │
└──────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

---

```
-- ORDERed BY ts
WITH d(ts, data) AS (
  VALUES
    (1 , 'json1'),
    (2 , 'json2'),
    (10, 'json10'),
    (3 , 'json3')
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(data, ',' ORDER BY ts)
FROM d
;
┌──────────────────────────┐
│        string_agg        │
├──────────────────────────┤
│ json1,json2,json3,json10 │
└──────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```